# Unable to call a function that is outside of a class, while being inside VM context

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Here's my main code:

```
const intents = {};

const characters = [
    new Character(0, 400, 300),
    new Character(1, 500, 200)
];

const vmContextMethods = require('./vm/context_methods.js')(characters);

const vmContext = {
    'intents': intents,
    'game': Object.freeze(vmContextMethods)
};

vm.createContext(vmContext);
vm.runInContext('characters[0].test();', vmContext, { displayErrors: true });
```

Here's the context_methods.js:

```
module.exports = function(characters) {
    const module = {
        characters
    }

    return module;
}
```

Here's the character class:

```
class Character {
    constructor(id, x, y) {
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    test() {
        intents.test = true;
    }
}

module.exports = Character;
```

I'm passing the intents object and the characters object to the VM context but I'm unable to reference the intents from within the character instances.

I'm able to reference the intents outside the character instance but not from inside.

My gut feeling is there's some sort of context / scope problem here since when I tested adding console.log(123); to the class, the 123 was sent to my server's console, instead of the client's console when all console.log() calls made from outside of the class came to my client's console (I passed custom console object to the VM context which sent the message to the client via socket.io).

I need something that's top context of the whole vm context. something like window, so I could use "window.intents" inside the game object (edited)

Comment: What's the goal of using the context in this case to begin with? Your `Character` object is created in the outer context, so the fact that you've made `intents` a global inside the context does not have any effect on it.

Comment: I'm trying to pass two different objects to the VM context, the intents and the character instances. I'd like to character instance to be able to refer the intents object. How can I do this? I've tried several different things but no cigar.

Comment: Since the class is declared outside the context, the `intents` object is loaded from the global outside the context. You're passing a reference to the object to the code running in the context, but that doesn't change how the `Character` instance behaves. Why does this need to be a global? You could just as easily pass the intents objects to the `Character` instances and avoid the global entirely.

Comment: This is actually something I just did. Thanks! Have an awesome weekend!

Answer (score 0):

I moved the intents object to the Character class. Not exactly an answer but I guess my original idea was bad.